# Delete whitespace for a  set of lines in Vim editor

Tags: text-processing, vim

I have some text like the following in a file:

```
  sample text
    some random text
            even more random text
text with no indent
 worst indention
```

I need to delete the empty space before each of the lines.
For one line what I do is
`0dw`

I can repeat the same command using . but by manually navigating to the next lines.

But is there a way to apply '0dw' to those block of lines?

I suppose there is a way using macros, but I haven't used them before. But I am willing to learn them if ther is no other choice.

Comment: +1 nice question, I end up doing a lot of the same thing. And welcome to the site.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
:%s/^\s\+
" Same thing (:le = :left = left-align given range):
:%le
```

Learn more here at 
http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Remove_unwanted_spaces

If you want to do this for a particular range of lines:

```
:19,25s/^\s\+//
```

BTW, best way to start learning vim is to execute `vimtutor` command, it will teach you how to use Vim in Vim editor.

Comment: :le was awesome and thanks a lot for the alternatives and the link :)

Comment: +1 for vimtutor mention as well as a good answer.

Comment: Select the relevant lines by using `V` and moving the cursor around to expand the line selection. Then press `:` to automatically enter `'<,'>`, and from there on you can use Nikhil's regexp.

Comment: another way of doing a range of lines (since I always forget the line numbers) is to mark the 2 lines and operate on the marks. Example, go to line 19 and press 'ma', go to line 25 and press 'mb', then do `:'a,'bs/^\s\+//`.

Answer (score 7):

An alternate way to do this is to use VIM's indentation tools (usually bound to <kbd><</kbd> / <kbd>></kbd>). First you need some way to indicate which lines will be affected. You can use the visual selection mode or any other means of specifying a range of lines to be affected, then use an arbitrarily high number or indentation levels to remove. `9<` usually does the trick quite nicely to remove at least 9 levels of possible indentation (tabs/spaces) from the current line(s).

Answer (score 4):

I have got approach to do this in the simple following steps:

```
1. press `v` to go to visual selection mode
2. select the lines you want to affect
3. :'<,'>normal 0dw
```

Explanation of the third step:

`0` navigates to start of line.

`dw` deletes the word (empty spaces).

`normal` applies the command `0dw`.

`'<,'>` repeats the normal for all selected lines in visual mode.

Answer (score 1):

`ctrl+v` allows you to do something similar to what you want but not exactly.  You can select a visual block and apply one command to the lot.

Comment: i selected those lines in block mode and this command worked:
:'<,'>normal 0dw

Comment: @saiy2k `:normal` is the important thing here, and I think it's the best answer here. Could you post it as an answer?